# CAPTCHA in java

Tags: java, authentication, captcha

I wanna give a shot at developing a secure login system in Java. How should I implement CAPTCHA using Java?

Comment: What kind of CAPTCHA system do you want? Word recognition; image recognition; something else? If you know how to program Java web apps generally, I don't think there's anything particularly challenging to do on the server side. What aspect are you not sure about?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The three CAPTCHA libraries I've used for Java are:

1. **JCaptcha** - This is the most configurable of the three, and pretty well documented. But we can't seem to get this to look right, no matter what. It also does audio and other unconventional CAPTCHAs
   [JCaptcha example http://jcaptcha.sourceforge.net/samples/SimpleListImageCaptchaEngineCaptcha_0.jpg](http://jcaptcha.sourceforge.net/samples/SimpleListImageCaptchaEngineCaptcha_0.jpg)
   http://jcaptcha.sourceforge.net/
2. **SimpleCaptcha** - This is reasonably configurable, and pretty well documented. I like the way this looks, but some people have trouble reading it.
   [SimpleCaptcha example http://simplecaptcha.sourceforge.net/images/Captcha.jpg](http://simplecaptcha.sourceforge.net/images/Captcha.jpg)
   http://simplecaptcha.sourceforge.net/
3. **icaptcha** - This is pretty poorly documented, but shouldn't be too hard to figure out from the examples. In our tests, we found this to be more readable than the other two (can be a good thing or a bad thing, depending on your target audience)
   [icaptcha example http://icaptcha.googlecode.com/files/2_img_test.jpg](http://icaptcha.googlecode.com/files/2_img_test.jpg)
   http://code.google.com/p/icaptcha/

Our apps are Spring MVC based, and it was really easy to integrate these.

We just went with what looked best to us (icaptcha).

Comment: JCaptcha is almost dead - it does not work on Java 8.

Answer (score 8):

I know it's an old question, but I would like to recommend [Cage](http://akiraly.github.com/cage/).

- open source, Apache v2 licensed so it can be used in enterprise/proprietary projects too
- supports maven (available from the central maven repository)
- fast (on the test pc 3-5 msec / image)
- small (a single, small jar, no external dependencies, only Java 1.5 or newer is needed)

[image: captcha 1]   [image: captcha2]

[image: captcha 3]   [image: captcha 4]

Answer (score 7):

[SimpleCaptcha](http://simplecaptcha.sourceforge.net/): SimpleCaptcha is a framework used in generating CAPTCHA image/answer pairs for Java (J2EE, Grails, JavaFX, etc.)

But I recommend [reCaptcha](http://recaptcha.net/)

Duplicate: [Recommendations for java captcha libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/810493/recommendations-for-java-captcha-libraries)

Answer (score 0):

Another captcha library with a Maven support and working Spring example: https://github.com/axet/kaptcha

Comment: Moved to https://gitlab.com/axet/kaptcha