# Offline captcha to use with JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, captcha, jsf-2.2

I am using JSF2 and Primefaces and currently I am using Primefaces captcha, and I was wondering about good offline captcha libraries that I can use with JSF.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recommendations for java captcha libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/810493/recommendations-for-java-captcha-libraries)

Comment: @Ravi, the post you mentioned is talking about java libraries in possible not the offline.

Comment: @MahmoudS Hi , Did you get a chance to try the JSF 2.0 and SimpleCaptcha give by Tilman Hausherr ?

Answer (score 3):

Did you try to use [BotDetect Java Captcha](https://captcha.com/java-captcha.html), which is offline captcha library?

As i see at the bottom of the https://captcha.com/java-captcha.html page, this library supports JavaServer Faces 2.0+ as well.