# How to add CAPTCHA to login form of Shibboleth IdP?

Tags: captcha, shibboleth

I want to show CAPTCHA in login form of Shibboleth after X failed logins. How can I do it? I am using Shibboleth IdP 3.3.1.1 and there is no Internet access in production environment, so I can't use something like Google reCAPTCHA.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for probably is local-offline captcha. Nothing to do with Shibboleth.

You can use [Simple Captcha](http://simplecaptcha.sourceforge.net/) or [Kaptcha](https://github.com/penggle/kaptcha) or any other such library.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/810493/recommendations-for-java-captcha-libraries) answer may be useful.

Comment: Actually, because I'm using login form of Shibboleth I'd like to know how to customize its login form to add CAPTCHA as well as how to process the entered value in the login form.