# Name of library which generates these captchas

Tags: captcha

On many different older pages, I have seen captchas like this, i.e. static JPG/PNG images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

All of these have a grey-to-white gradient and wobbly lines in the background, as well as distorted sans-serif characters (only a-z and 0-9) as the captcha text, which is why I assume that they all come from the same library. Probably the standard settings of this library are used, leading to a similar appearance on different pages.

The bottom two images come from [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/248380891_captcha_dataset) dataset, part of the paper [A Comparison of Supervised Learning Algorithms to Solve CAPTCHAs](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/248380881_A_Comparison_of_Supervised_Learning_Algorithms_to_Solve_CAPTCHAs). Unfortunately, I did not find a mention of the used captcha generation algorithm in that paper though. Notably, the Keras example page [OCR model for reading Captchas](https://keras.io/examples/vision/captcha_ocr/) also uses this dataset. The page [PWNtcha](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/PWNtcha) does not list this kind of captcha either.

So, can someone tell me which library it actually is?

Answer (score 2):

I found it, it's a library called [kaptcha](https://code.google.com/archive/p/kaptcha/) (Internet Archive version of the Google Code page [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20081122115556/http://kaptcha.googlecode.com/)), which seems to be a fork of the [SimpleCaptcha](http://simplecaptcha.sourceforge.net) Java library. kaptcha was created by Jon Stevens (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2182257)), who cloned the Google Code repo to GitHub [here](https://github.com/lookfirst/kaptcha). GitHub user penggle has also [cloned that repository](https://github.com/penggle/kaptcha) and made it [available on Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.penggle/kaptcha/2.3.2).

To try it out without spinning up a huge Maven project, e.g. to generate a lot of training data for a machine learning algorithm, do the following:

1. Download `kaptcha-2.3.2.zip` from kaptcha's [downloads page](https://code.google.com/archive/p/kaptcha/downloads).
2. From that ZIP file, extract `kaptcha-2.3.2.jar` and put it into a new directory.
3. In the directory of the JAR file, create a new file called `Main.java` and put the following code into it. As expected, all these pages just use the default settings from the file `src/java/com/google/code/kaptcha/util/Config.java` in the ZIP. Of course you can replace the use of `DefaultTextCreator` (which even only uses the letters `abcde2345678gfynmnpwx` by default) by any string you want.

```java
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import com.google.code.kaptcha.util.Config;
import com.google.code.kaptcha.impl.DefaultKaptcha;
import com.google.code.kaptcha.text.impl.DefaultTextCreator;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        Config config = new Config(properties);
        
        DefaultKaptcha kaptcha = new DefaultKaptcha();
        kaptcha.setConfig(config);
        DefaultTextCreator textCreator = new DefaultTextCreator();
        textCreator.setConfig(config);
        
        BufferedImage image = kaptcha.createImage(textCreator.getText());
        
        File output = new File("out.jpg");
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", output);
    }
}
```

4. Run this Java code using the following two shell commands:

```
javac -cp kaptcha-2.3.2.jar Main.java
java -cp kaptcha-2.3.2.jar:. Main
```

5. The output JPG you will get will look like this:

[image: example output]

6. To change the config, add the line `import com.google.code.kaptcha.Constants;` at the top of `Main.java` and then, for example, add the command `properties.setProperty(Constants.KAPTCHA_BORDER, "no");` before creating the `Config` object:

[image]